# How to check if ip already exists in MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ip

This is my code, but it's not working; what's wrong?

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$con=mysqli_connect("DBHOST","DBUSER","DBPASS","DBNAME");
$check= 'SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip = '.$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$rs = $con->query($check);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
if( $row_cnt > 0 ) echo $row_cnt.' Records found';
```

Comment: `$check= "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."'";`   Or `$check= "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip = '".$ip."'";` since you've already assigned a variable. Plus, your table and column are indeed named `ip`?

Comment: You've got to enclose the IP address in single quotes. Better use a prepared statement with a placeholder and bind your value to this placeholder to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

The ip is not a number, it is a text (or varchar). This is why you have to use:

$check= "SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ip = '{$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]}'";

Comment: ok now work.but i use two check: username,ip .but not work together

Comment: @user3742472: that's a simple logical `AND`. Please consider using prepared statements with placeholders. It will save you some headache later on.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you only need get count use COUNT()

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."'";
```